# jQuery, create the next div when the number of the anchors goes over 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Script:

```
<script>
    var currentPage = 1;

    function page(pg)
    {
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName("pagecontainer");
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
        {
            var page_of_container = els[i].getAttribute("id");
            els[i].style.display = page_of_container  == pg ? 'block' : 'none';                    
        }

        currentPage = pg;
    }

    function prev()
    {
        if (currentPage <= 1) return;

        page(currentPage -1);
    }

    function next()
    {
        if (currentPage >= document.getElementsByClassName("pagecontainer").length) return;

        page(currentPage + 1);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:
I'm going to have this HTML only,

```
<div id="1" class="pagecontainer" style="display: block;">
<a href="#">Contents goes here</a>
<a href="#">Contents goes here</a>
<a href="#">Contents goes here</a>
-
-
-
- 10 a elements
<p class="page"></p>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
    <a href="#" onclick="prev()">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="page('1')"></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="page('2')"></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="next()">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

and i need from the script to create:

```
<div id="2" class="pagecontainer" style="display: block;">
    <a href="#">Contents goes here</a>
    <a href="#">Contents goes here</a>
    <p class="page"></p>
    </div>
```

---

I'm using it for useful links block so all the contents going to be LINKS, and the script is working well with static content by creating divs id=1, id=2, id=3, what i need is to make it dynamic by using one div and let the script create the next divs when the number of the anchors goes over 10 for example,

how can i achieve that, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the end-result you'd like to achieve? Given thirty `a` elements, how should the HTML/DOM look after it's been processed?

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop through each `anchor` and add it to an array, then when the loop count reaches 10 create the new divider and assign accordingly.

```
var container = [];

$('a[href]').each(function() {
    container.push($(this));

    var containerLength = container.length;

    if(containerLength  === 10 || !$(this).next().is('a[href]'))
    {
        var containingDivider = $('<div></div>');
        containingDivider.insertBefore(container[0]);

        for(i=0;i<containerLength;i++)
            container.shift().appendTo(containingDivider);

        container.length = 0;
    }
});
```

The `!$(this).next().is('a[href]')` ensures that the next element is an anchor with a `href` property - if it isn't it means we've either reached the end of the anchors or reached something which isn't an anchor.

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nxkv/2/) of this in use.